# Is it safe to replace a battery with one that has a lower max charge current?

Tags: circuit, battery, vacuum

I'm trying to replace the batteries on my hand vacuum (black and decker CHV1410L), and having pulled out the batteries, they're using some 18650s (I've never worked with them, but there's a spec sheet [here](https://voltaplex.com/media/whitepapers/specification-sheet/LG_HB7_Specification_Sheet.pdf)). I can't find these specific ones, so I was looking at [these](https://www.18650batterystore.com/products/eve-18650-25p):

The specs seem similar, but the LGs are rated for a higher charge current. Would it be safe to use the EVE batteries in place of the LG ones? Is there any other glaring issue I'm missing in the spec sheets?

If it matters, there is a circuit board that I'm guessing might offer some sort of protection for charging, but I'm not sure.

Comment: as long the charging voltage is the same it is safe to use

Comment: check the output current of the AC/DC wall wort; i highly doubt it's putting out more than an amp or 2, well under the max battery charge current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it safe to use a battery rated for a lower current than what’s required? No.

That said, when I look at the specs for the batteries you linked, I’m drawing a different conclusion about the battery rating:

- [LG HB7](https://voltaplex.com/media/whitepapers/specification-sheet/LG_HB7_Specification_Sheet.pdf) (original):

  - Standard charge: 750 mA
  - Fast charge: 4000 mA
  - Standard discharge: 300 mA
  - Fast discharge: 10000 mA
- [EVE INR18650/25P](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0481/9678/0183/files/EVE_INR18650-25P_Spec_RD-EVE_INR18650-25P-S47-LF_1.pdf) (replacement):

  - Standard charge: 1250 mA
  - Fast charge: 4000 mA
  - Standard discharge: 500 mA
  - Fast discharge: 30000 mA

This suggests to me that the replacement battery has a higher current rating than the original.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I was looking at Max charge current (6A) on the LG, vs 4A on the EVE. Is that metric less important than the other ones? But I guess both list 4A for Fast/Rapid charge...

Comment: It is not less important, but most equipment don't charge at max charge rate. You can check this yourself by knowing the charge time or charger power output.